# How can I make multiple subcommands that do the same thing

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap

```rust
#[derive(Parser)]
struct Cli {
    #[clap(subcommand)]
    subcommand: Subcommand,
}


#[derive(clap::Subcommand)]
enum Subcommand {
    Index {
        #[clap(parse(from_os_str))]
        path: path::PathBuf,
    },
    Show {
        item: Option<String>,
    },
    Cd {
        term: String,
    },
    List,
    Init {
        shell: InitShell,
    },
    Search {
        term: Option<String>,
    },
    Add {
        category: String,
        title: String,
    },
}

fn main(){
    let cli = Cli::parse();

    match cli.subcommand{
        Subcommand::Index=>{/*code here*/}
        Subcommand::Show=>{/*and here*/}
        Subcommand::Display=>{/*and also here*/}
        Subcommand::Cd=>{}
        Subcommand::List=>{}
    // ... more matches
    }
}
```

When I run my program with `--help`, the subcommands section looks like this:

```
SUBCOMMANDS:
    add
    cd
    help
    index
    init
    list
    search
    show
```

I would like to define some aliases, such as `ls` for `list` or `display` for `show`, so that
the help looks something like this:

```
SUBCOMMANDS:
    add
    cd, path
    help
    index
    init
    list, ls
    search
    show, display
```

I can see that cargo does something like this, with `cargo build` equal to `cargo b`.

I looked at the clap documentation and was able to find an [alias function](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/builder/struct.App.html#method.alias) for the builder api,
but I could not find how to do this with the derive api.  Is is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_derive/index.html#possible-value-attributes `#[clap(alias("foo"))]`

Comment: @PitaJ Thank you, this works.  Is it possible to show the alias next to the subcommand, like in cargo?  (run `cargo --help` to see)

Comment: You probably want `visible_alias` instead of just `alias`, then.

Comment: @PitaJ Please post answers as answer instead of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Clap derive docs say (under [Possible Value Attributes](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_derive/index.html#possible-value-attributes)):

> #### Possible Value Attributes
>
> These correspond to a [`PossibleValue`][crate::PossibleValue].
>
> **Raw attributes:**  Any [`PossibleValue` method][crate::PossibleValue] can also be used as an attribute, see
> Terminology for syntax.
>
> - e.g. `#[clap(alias("foo"))]` would translate to `pv.alias("foo")`

You also say you wish the aliases to show up under `help`. In that case, you want to use [`visible_alias`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/builder/struct.Arg.html#method.visible_alias) instead:

```rust
#[clap(visible_alias("foo"))]
```